# animate scrollTop all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am modifying an existing Wordpress theme (creating a child theme) and it won't scroll to top the top of the page for some reason, could use an extra pair of eyes on this one.

Firing any of the following code in the console (or on page) fails:

```
$("#wrapper").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, function(){});
$("body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, function(){});
$("html").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, function(){});
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, function(){});
```

Have been looking into what could make it fail, overflows and positioning but can't see what I am sure is an obvious error. So an extra pair of eyes would be appreciated, thanks :)

#### [Page with the problem](http://annabogdanova.dk/dokumentar/)

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser console.

Comment: nope, would have noticed that

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: newest I think... version 3.0.0

Comment: Hi, `$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');` this works. And also I found that  `$('#wrapper').scrollTop()` is always `0`(Check how and where `#wrapper` is placed in DOM).

Comment: @RohithKP nope doesn't work here, in neither Edge, FF or chrome..

Comment: @RohithKP as I stated in the initial post I have already checked to see if it's overflow or positioning. And unless I have gone blind it isn't :)

Comment: I haven't bound it to the button since the code doesn't work in the console.. so didn't bother ;)

The problem is either with some styling or with some javascript that conflicts, but for the devil of me, I can't find the problem.

Comment: Try to disable plugins' scripts one by one. I think some of the plugins makes conflict with your function. Also, `$(window).scrollTop(0)` worked for me.

Comment: $(window).scrollTop(0) worked for me aswell, GERAT! thanks that points me in the direction of somestyling or scripting probably on the HTML and/or Body elemt.. GREAT! find now I have something to look for atleast.. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Seems like all animations are disabled, slideUp or FadeIn don't work so isn't a problem of the function itself; must be with the way you migrate ... are you sure you are migrating from a version higher than 1.9 ?

Comment: @DaniP your on to something he, because I took the lazy way out and handled the jQuery update via a plugin (that was suppose to always update to newest version) seems that might have been the problem.. I'll look into it, thanks a ton!

Comment: You are getting an error in your console now _TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function_

Comment: Also try to disable scrollTo plugin first.

Comment: @DanPhilip yeah you checked the page while I was editing a script, hence the error. But thanks for taking the time to look at the problem :)

Comment: @Reborn Have you checked the jQuery migrate beacause when I set the scrollTop directly its working, the issue occurs when I try to set it throught `animate()`.